# Amplification using an ac and dc sources in series

Tags: transistors, ac, dc, capacitance

I was wondering about the use of CE transistors as amplifiers.

At the base of the transistor we use AC+DC to vary the voltage across BE diode, which in turn creates a variable DC and then we use a capacitor to generate an AC again by using a capacitor at the output side of the transistor.

The question is that if AC and DC can be mixed to generate a powerful variable DC and AC can be taken out using a capacitor in series then why use a transistor. We can simply use AC and DC sources in series and get a powerful AC like varying signal and later connect a capacitor in series to block the DC and separate the AC.

So input DC + AC a capacitor and the output at the other plate of the cap.

Why employ a transistor or a vacuum tube?

Comment: "Creates a variable DC" what? ...Also, in this context, "DC" means "not changing in time", not "always the same sign", so the idea of a "variable DC" voltage or current is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 0):

Although magnetic amplifiers were used to control battleship turrents, the classic means of generating power-gain is via transductors: devices that convert input voltage changes into output current changes.

OpAmps use these: vacuum tubes, varactor balanced-bridge diodes, bipolar transistors, Field Effect transistors.

Have you examined load lines: of triodes for example?

[image]

Draw a straight line from 150 volts, on bottom axis, to 15mA on left axis. That is your load line.

Changing the grid voltage from -3v to -1v will increase the plate current by 5mA. What is the output power? approximately [120v - 70v] volts, times 5mA = 50v * 0.005 = 0.25 watts.
Life is good, with a device providing power gain.